# Retrieve any "liked" URL

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

If I create a facebook like button with data-href = "www.ohohohoho.com"

and ... some people like it.

How can I know if my logged user likes it with the SDK or Graph or FDK ? I saw that I can only retrieve the kind of

referenced page with :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671094/retrieve-non-facebook-liked-pages-from-a-facebook-user

by doing :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/
```

But the rest not :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant get users that liked it. But you can know if determined user liked this.

Comment: How can I do that ? that's what I need in fact. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes this is it but I don't understand something. I have this page : exchangemyrooms.com I liked the URL, (my like button has this parameter data-href="exchangemyrooms.com";) When I use the url_like table, some URLs (like mine) don't appear, why ?

Comment: I used the link_stat table to check your url, and what i see is that your url dont have a LIKE but a SHARE. I dont know why this, but i think that liking a url outside of facebook.com its counts a share and not a like.